# MongoDB replica set - copyDatabase with readPreference?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database

From the docs on [Connection String URI Syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-with-read-distribution) with respect to replica sets we have:

> The following connects to a replica set with three members and distributes reads to the secondaries:

```
mongodb://example1.com,example2.com/?replicaSet=test&readPreference=secondary
```

This is exactly what I need to do, however I'm trying to determine the correct syntax to use (and if `readPreference` is even supported) for the `copyDatabase` command.  Its host URI syntax looks like this:

```
test/example1.com,example2.com
```

...for example...

```
db.copyDatabase('myDb', 'myDb', 'test/example1.com,example2.com')
```

Can I tack `?readPreference=secondary` on the end of that and have it work as expected?  I don't have a convenient way to test this myself in my environment or I would.  Hoping someone here may know off the top of their head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A read preference is a client/driver-side concept. The server is not aware of the read preference of a request so you can't verify read preference on the server side. You can verify that some queries are sent to secondaries via, e.g., `mongostat` or you can use `db.serverStatus().opcounters` on each DB server compare 'query' count pre-querying and post-querying. for entire list of db server status, use `db.serverStatus()`

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I hadn't considered that it was managed client-side.  Docs are "a bit" thin.  :)  Many thanks